# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs at configuring hardware during install

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I have a HP Pavilion x360 that I tried to install Ubuntu Studio 16.04 and the regular 16.04 on. In both cases it hangs at configuring hardware. Here's the kind of stuff I'm seeing in the dialog box.

/usr/lib/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:17: Warning Source ID 20535 was not found when attempting to remove it GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)

/usr/lib/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:133: Warning Source ID 21752 was not found when attempting to remove it GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)

Basically keeps spitting this out for increasing Source ID values. Any help would be appreciated because right now I just have a $300 paperweight.